# PostgreSQL - join tables using pattern matching

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, pattern-matching

I have two tables and need to join them using two columns that are similar.

The first table is called articles has a column called 'slug' with slug lines for articles, ex: 'trump-fails-yet-again.'

The second table is called log and has a column called path with the url path for the articles, ex: '/articles/trump-fails-yet-again/'

Here is my search query:

```
"SELECT articles.title, count(*) as num FROM articles, log WHERE articles.slug LIKE CONCAT('%',log.path) GROUP BY articles.title;"
```

This returns nothing but brackets, []

I have also tried:

```
"SELECT articles.title, count(*) as num FROM articles JOIN log ON articles.slug SIMILAR TO CONCAT('%',log.path) GROUP BY articles.title;"
```

That returns a DataError: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm confused when you pay pattern matching, you mean you just want to replace spaces with '-' on the join condition?

Comment: I need to match the slug line to the log path after /articles/

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
` select articles.title, count(*) as views from articles
  join log on articles.slug ~~ ('%' || articles.slug || '%') 
  group by articles.title;`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a slash at the end of the path.  How about this?

```
SELECT a.title, count(*) as num
FROM articles a JOIN
     log l
     ON a.path LIKE '%' || l.slug || '%'
GROUP BY a.title;
```

You should also learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: This returns no errors but still only returns a table with 0 rows.

Comment: @JTP709 . . . The logic was backwards.  The `slug` should be in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a 1:1 function with this you can do this

```
SELECT articles.title, count(*) as num
FROM articles
JOIN log ON articles.slug = '/articles/' || articles.slug || '/'
GROUP BY articles.title;
```

Or even better

```
CREATE FUNCTION slug_to_article_path( slug text )
RETURNS text AS
$$
  SELECT '/articles/' || slug || '/';
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

SELECT articles.title, count(*) as num
FROM articles
JOIN log ON articles.slug = slug_to_article_path(articles.slug)
GROUP BY articles.title;
```